# How to fill values between two factors in R?

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, stata

How to fill the 'duration' column with 1 between 'start' and 'end' indicators as the examples below?

In Stata it would be:

```
by id (year), sort: gen duration=1 if start==1
by id (year), sort: replace duration=1 if duration[_n-1]==1 & end!=1
```

How could I do this in R, possibly using Dplyr?

```
id  year    start   end 
1   2000    0       0   
1   2001    1       0   
1   2002    0       0   
1   2003    0       1   
1   2004    0       0   
2   2000    0       0   
2   2001    0       0   
2   2002    1       0   
2   2003    0       0   
2   2004    0       1
```

Output would be:

```
id  year    start   end duration
1   2000    0       0   0
1   2001    1       0   1
1   2002    0       0   1
1   2003    0       1   0
1   2004    0       0   0
2   2000    0       0   0
2   2001    0       0   0
2   2002    1       0   1
2   2003    0       0   1
2   2004    0       1   0
```

Comment: `unlist(by(dat, dat$id, FUN=function(x) cumsum(x$start) - cumsum(x$end)))` or `setDT(dat)[, dur:=cumsum(start)-cumsum(end), by=id]` perhaps..

Comment: If you could give more information on what you are trying to do, that would be helpful, otherwise it's difficult to understand what you are trying to do (without digging out STATA Documentation and trying to reverse engineer what you have written)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `dplyr`, this seems to do the trick. First, the sample data

```
dd<-read.table(text="id  year    start   end 
1   2000    0       0   
1   2001    1       0   
1   2002    0       0   
1   2003    0       1   
1   2004    0       0   
2   2000    0       0   
2   2001    0       0   
2   2002    1       0   
2   2003    0       0   
2   2004    0       1", header=T)
```

now we just group by ID, then we use `cumsum` to look for changes in start and end

```
library(dplyr)
dd %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(duration = cumsum(start-end))

#       id  year start   end duration
#    (int) (int) (int) (int)    (int)
# 1      1  2000     0     0        0
# 2      1  2001     1     0        1
# 3      1  2002     0     0        1
# 4      1  2003     0     1        0
# 5      1  2004     0     0        0
# 6      2  2000     0     0        0
# 7      2  2001     0     0        0
# 8      2  2002     1     0        1
# 9      2  2003     0     0        1
# 10     2  2004     0     1        0
```

Comment: Cool shortcut to it. The OP might also be interested in `arrange(year)` since that sorting was part of the Stata code.

Comment: Very nice @MrFlick. But what if I'd like to include the last year where end =1? That is, fill id 1 including 2003 and id 2 including 2004?

Comment: @Rodrigo `dd %>% group_by(id) %>% mutate(duration = cumsum(start-lag(end, def=0L)))`

Answer (score 1):

Using similar logic to the code you provided:

```
#Load dplyr
require(dplyr)

#Make data
df <- data.frame("id" = c(1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2),
             "year" = c(2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004),
             "start" = c(0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0),
             "end" = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1))

#Order by Year and ID
df <- df[order(df$id,df$year),]

#Make new variable
df$duration <- 0
df$duration[df$start==1 & df$end != 1] <- 1
df$duration[lag(df$duration,1)==1 & df$end ==0] <-1
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `base R`

```
df1$duration <- with(df1, ave(start-end, id, FUN = cumsum))
df1
#   id year start end duration
#1   1 2000     0   0        0
#2   1 2001     1   0        1
#3   1 2002     0   0        1
#4   1 2003     0   1        0
#5   1 2004     0   0        0
#6   2 2000     0   0        0
#7   2 2001     0   0        0
#8   2 2002     1   0        1
#9   2 2003     0   0        1
#10  2 2004     0   1        0
```